# Can we disable maximize button in any software(gedit or terminal)?

Tags: gnome

Can We disable maximize button in any software (Gedit &terminal) ?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If talking about `gnome-shell`,

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

also you can use the utility `dconf-editor`.

The default value for the layout of the applications menu is 'appmenu:close' so with only the close button.

Comment: i want to disable maximize button

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu:close,minimize'` gives you close and minimize but maximize buttons

Comment: (process:5343): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

Comment: There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=975521) related, at this moment the fix is deleting the file `~/.config/dconf/user`